# IDE: Find a SCSS line from a CSS selector

Tags: css, sass, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Let's say I have the following `example.scss` file:

```css
body{
    #test{
        p{
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way, in an IDE like PhpStorm, to search for the CSS selector **`body #test p`** and obtain in result the files and lines which correspond to this selector?

**In my case:** `example.scss - line 3`

Comment: It looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-40411/Add-the-ability-to-search-for-a-CSS-rules-when-using-nested-selectors-SASS-SCSS-or-LESS

Comment: @Oksana exactly. I guess if the team hasn't replied in 4 years it's because this feature doesn't exist (yet).

Answer (score -2):

On Intellij, for example, you can make a ctrl+click on the class/id located on html tag, in your case it could be

```html
<button id="test">myButton</button>
```

Just hold ctrl and click on the id, if it is referenced on a css/scss file, intelliJ automatically detect where to locate you.

Hope this respond to your question